# NSPredicate problems with NOT, AND

Tags: ios

I am using the following format string

`(NOT (relatedClassrooms.id CONTAINS %d)) AND relatedLanguage.id = %d`

With the following arguments list

`[98, 1]`

The result returns all objects even though I know there are objects that should be filtered out. Strangely, if I remove the `NOT` from the format string, then the predicate behaves as expected. What am I doing wrong?

See this Xcode project demonstrating the issue in GitHub [CoreData test project](https://github.com/rzil/QueryTest)

Comment: [Edit] your question showing actual, relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. This:

`(NOT (relatedClassrooms.id CONTAINS %d)) AND relatedLanguage.id = %d`

is wrong. It should be:

`SUBQUERY(relatedClassrooms, $a, $a.id = %d).@count = 0 AND relatedLanguage.id = %d`